# When to use Microservices & DDD in Laravel Project

Tags: laravel, domain-driven-design

**Hello**

> i'm wondring when i use microservices pattern in laravel & when to use
> DDD?

i searched about it without no results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. What kind of domain are you dealing with? How complex should the application be?

From your question, there are three things to consider: 1. Should you use microservice pattern? 2. Should you use DDD? 3. Should you use Laravel?

1. Microservices are usually used when you have clear organizational structure consisting of large teams. Microservices enable independent deployment, so that a deployment of a service have minimal effect on another. Microservices are *usually* divided using DDD approach, although you don't have to. Check out this video in which it discusses when to use microservice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GBTdnfD6s5Q&t=1559s
2. Domain-driven design is an approach which you design a system based on domain knowledge. If you have a small project, and/or you are also the domain expert, you probably don't have to use DDD. However, DDD might be useful to tackle more complex domain which you may not be the domain expert, because it enables smooth communication between your domain experts and your developers. You can also define boundaries of ubiquitous language, which may be useful to divide your microservices.
3. Laravel is a PHP framework. For your usecase, can PHP fulfill your requirements? PHP is usually great at a more intensive computation task, but slows down noticeably compared to NodeJS. You can find out more about the benchmarks out there. For a framework, Laravel comes with robust features and great code and support, although it comes at a cost of performance. If you want to use microservice, Lumen might be a better choice (it's a lightweight version of Laravel). But then again, if PHP can't fulfill your requirements, you might probably be better off with another language and another frameworks, probably ExpressJS/Spring.

Personally, I have used Laravel in a monolithic-modular fashion, with Onion Architecture for each modules, and design and implement the model of all of them with DDD. It works great so far for my usecase.

Answer (score 0):

Microservice is architecture style but DDD is architecture pattern.
in other words, You can use Microservice for external architecture and DDD or Simple CRUD, or Onion for internal architecture as a service inside your microservice.
You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/microservice-application-design#external-versus-internal-architecture-and-design-patterns) from Microsoft

In below picture you can figure out this concept better:

[image]